# How to ignore blocking system errors from a child process on windows

Tags: c#, windows, child-process, system-error

I have a C# application running in Visual Studio 2015. It accepts arbitrary executable files and opens a command prompt through which it attempts to run them. Nothing is guaranteed about these executables though, so it is possible for them to fail to run, throwing a system error that says something like "could not locate xxx.dll". For a particular example, see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgeLz.jpg). These system errors (The header of the window sometimes says "XXXXX.exe - System Error") block the child process from ending, and since the parent process is waiting on the child, it blocks the parent too. It blocks until a human can come along and press the button, letting the child process die and the parent process continue. I need this to happen automatically without human intervention, preferably by just having these errors not come up in the first place. Looking around online, I was able to disable Windows Error Reporting through the use of regedit. While this does ignore errors such as "XXXXX.exe has stopped working", it does not ignore the system errors such as the one I linked. How can I ignore this kind of errors?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you linked shows a DLL import failure where a function was loaded by id instead of its name (which often occurs when your program is a different version of the dll than expected). I do not know of any way how to stop this message from appearing in the first place.

However, as the child executable is still running (showing this dialogue box), you can find this window and close it from code.

This is quite easy, as your parent process must know the child process id. From there you can use [`FindWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500) or [`EnumWindows`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497) to retrieve your dialogue handle (by specifying the appropriate window class name) and then use [`CloseWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632678) to close it.

Note: you have to use P/Invoke to use these functions.

Maybe not the most elegant solution but definitely working.